# Mark just a portion of the page as "canonical" when some blog content is used on product pages

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, canonical-url

Our site has blog posts and product pages. Some of our product pages contain, among some other information, part of the blog posts' content. I am not sure how Google will see it. Am I going to be penalized for "duplicating" and "cannibalizing" my content from some of my own blog posts?

I don't want to add a canonical tag either because the rest of the information on the page is different, is just that specific part (let says 10 to 20 paragraphs) that's the same. What can be done in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

Not directly no. You could do it with the content in an iframe and having the page loaded within the iframe being canonical to the original blog.

If you're including snippets with a link to the full blog, then no problem - especially if you just make the whole snippet a link (although this isn't practical with 10 to 20 paragraphs, even short ones).

If the blog content is on the same website then you won't be penalised for re-using it (although, do be aware, I can't say what effect it would have across separate subdomains). You won't see a drop in PageRank for duplicate content on the same site. Google actually differentiates this themselves with their best practice guidelines, talking about *copied content* not *duplicate content*.

That being said, is there a good usability reason to include huge tracts (and 10 to 20 paragraphs is a huge tract) from one page on another page of the same site that adds to user experience?